# Usage of aws ios sdk for iphone app

Tags: ios, sdk, amazon-web-services

We are in the development of an iOS(iPhone) application that consumes a web services. We are planning to host our web service (ReSTful web services) in the AWS. Initially we planned to use `Restkit` or `ASIHttpRequest` libraries for invoking the web services. Our web services contains `GET`, `POST` api and some image uploading for setting the profile photos of the users. Also we are sending video, audio files in to the database and accessing these files through web services. We are using `JSON` as our output format.

While searching through the web we found that AWS SDK for iOS is [this](http://aws.amazon.com/sdkforios/). Can somebody advice us is it possible to do the above requirements (GET/POST/Upload Photo/etc) using AWS SDK for iOS? Or shall we continue with other third-party libraries like Restkit or ASIHttpRequest.

Please advise us.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use both `ASIHttpRequest` and `Amazon SDK for IOS` at the same time.You would want to use Amazon S3 service (by creating a bucket) for your media files.Amazon S3 is cheap,fast and easy to use.  When you download AWS SDK you can see `sample` folder and an example of `S3_Uploader` for ios.

For example in my latest app user upload their photos to Amazon S3 and comment&vote to other user pictures etc... I use AWS SDK to upload pictures to the Amazon S3 service. While uploading photos with AWS SDK I keep URL,path, of the photos in a  database and use `ASIHttpRequest` , `POST`to update my MYSQL database, which is in another server. When I fetch data from my server I use `JSON` and AWS SDK.

So If I were you, I would use Amazon S3 for my files(photo,video etc...) and I would use either Amazon EC2 or another web service for rest of the database. I am assuming you keep your data in a database and interact thru `GET` and `POST` methods. If so keeping media files and database in separate places would be my choice

Comment: Ok thank you for your answer. For your answer "When I fetch data from my server I use JSON and AWS SDK.". In this case also I can use ASIHttpRequest to invoke the GET ReSTFul API?

Comment: In theory it should work for example `ASIFormDataRequest *request = [ASIFormDataRequest requestWithURL:url];
[request setPostValue:@"Ben" forKey:@"first_name"];` is my post method to add or update values in my database.  This tutorial  very very nicely explains what you need [http://www.raywenderlich.com/2941/how-to-write-a-simple-phpmysql-web-service-for-an-ios-app], [http://www.raywenderlich.com/2965/how-to-write-an-ios-app-that-uses-a-web-service]